# Protractor - ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout - From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

Everything worked out OK yesterday.
Today I did an update to get all commits from svn and nothing works anymore.

Whenever I run a test I get this error:

```
ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout
```

And:

```
From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, #test)
```

Basically it fails on login page before sending the inputs in the username and password fields.
Nothing changed in my code since yesterday, and yes, it is an angular page, so `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` would not work here.

Any idea?
I tried everything.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual spec fille

Comment: We resolved it, it was a commit that broke it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved. A change in the latest commit broke it.